# find indices x,y of a matrix of specific values in python

Tags: python, matrix, multidimensional-array, indices

I convert a list of integers to a two dimensinal array like this:

```
data = numpy.array( l )
shape = ( 10, 30 )
data = data.reshape( shape )
```

I try to get the indices x,y of the matrix of the values that are bigger than some threshold and lower than some other threshold.

I tried to make the next but it provides some errors:

```
data_indices = numpy.where(data<=obj_value_max and data>=obj_value_min)
```

The error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `where` line to something like:

```
data_indices = numpy.where((data<=obj_value_max) & (data>=obj_value_min))
```

Notice the `()s` around each conditional clause and the use of `&` (meaning "and").  This works because in numpy, `<,<=,>,>=,&,|,...` are overridden, i.e. they act differently than in native python.  `and` and `or` cannot be overridden, and this is why you get the error message you get.

To get pairs of indices for each value (instead of (array of x indices, array of y indices)), do

```
zip(*data_indices)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, it works now! but may I ask another q?If I print the data_indices I get: (array([  0,   0,   0, ..., 599, 599, 599], dtype=int64), array([ 20,  33,  36, ..., 783, 792, 799], dtype=int64))
How, can I get it like in a dictionary?

Comment: What is your end goal?  Do you want to get an (x, y) pair for value of data such that `value_min => data >= value_min`?  The output you have is essentially `(array_of_x_inds, array_of_y_inds)`.

Comment: Yes, I want a pairs of `(x,y)` like you wrote: `(array_of_x_inds, array_of_y_inds)`

Comment: Just do `zip(*data_indices)`.