# I want to create a list from rows and column of a picture

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, image-processing, plot

I have a 2D binary video with a value of 0 or 255. I would like to find the pixels with a value of 255 in a specific range of rows and columns in each image and plot the column value of them continuously. I found the rows (x values) and columns (y values) of pixels with a value of 255 in the following program, however I cannot create a list of rows and a list of columns separately to plot the column values continuously. Please find below my program.

```
for row in range(0,700):
        for column in range(354):
            if thresh[row][column]==255:
                print(row,column)
```

Could you please help me to create a list of row values and column values separately and plot them continuously using matplotlib?

Comment: If you want a `Matplotlib`solution, please add that tag. If you have a `2D binary video` to plot, please share it (Dropbox or Google Drive or similar). If you have code to calculate what you want to plot, please share it. If you have an idea how the output should look, please share it. Thank you.

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987455/find-indices-x-y-of-a-matrix-of-specific-values-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use a simple matrix as an example:

```
A = [[1, 255, 5], 
    [-5, 8, 9]]
```

The objective is to print indices with a value of 255.

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(A[i])):
        if A[i][j]==255:
            print(i,j)
```

Which returns `0 1` in this case.